# Помогите понять формулировку

Tags: python

Я столкнулся с задачей где вообще не понимаю формулировку. Вот оно:

> Структурные лингвисты называют особыми строки, начинающиеся и заканчивающиеся одним и тем же символом. Вам дана строка, состоящая из заглавных латинских букв, ваша задача - определить самую длинную её подстроку, являющуюся особой строкой, и вывести её длину.
> Напоминаем, что подстрока определяется как строка, составленная из элементов строки, начиная с i-го и заканчивая j-м. Если i<j, то подстрока пустая. Если i==j, подстрока состоит из одного символа. Если i совпадает с началом строки, а j - с концом, то подстрока совпадает с самой строкой.

Буду рад помощи с объяснением.

Comment: `abcbacbd` ответ 6 - от первой b до последней bcbacb. Кроме того, есть особые строки длиной 5 (abcba) и менее

Comment: *«Если i<j, то подстрока пустая. »* - Должно быть наоборот: Если **i>j**, то подстрока пустая.

Comment: @MarianD это вы уже сами придумываете. ТЗ дано так как оно дано ;-)

Comment: @Kromster, да, вы прав. ;-)

Comment: Пусть тахорги в страхе воют,
Издавая визг и писк!
Ведь на них идет войною
Структуральнейший лингвист!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примеры **особых строк** (из заглавных латинских букв):

- **A**RI**A**
- **R**OTATO**R**
- **D**EFINE**D**
- **X**ABCDEFG**X**

Примеры строк, которые не являются особыми, но *содержат особую подстроку:*

- ZEN**ARIA**H
- UN**ROTATOR** (содержит тоже другие особые подстроки, напр. UNR**OTATO**R)
- PRE**DEFINED**TERM (тоже содержит и другие особые строки)
- YZ**XABCDEFGX**KLM

Ваша задача — определить **самую длинную** особую подстроку.

Когда вам дана строка, которая *уже особая* (как в первой части моих примеров), то *она сама* будет самой длинной её особой «подстрокой».

Самые длинные особые подстроки для второй части моих примеров:

- для ZEN**ARIA**H:   `ARIA`
- для UN**ROTATOR**:  `ROTATOR`
- для P**REDEFINEDTER**M:  `REDEFINEDTER`
- для YZ**XABCDEFGX**KLM:  `XABCDEFGX`

---

*Как в Питоне найти такую подстроку?*

Подстрока данной строки — начиная с i-го и заканчивая j-м символом — в Питоне записывается так:

```
original[i:j+1]
```

Один метод состоит в проверке всех таких подстрок, т.е. для всех пар `(i, j)` для `i <= j`, в диапазоне от `(0, 0)` до `(длина_строки - 1, длина_строки - 1)`.

Такая подстрока является особой, когда `original[i] == original[j]`.